# extern int i. так определение это или объявление?

Tags: c++, компиляция, линковка, extern

запутался совсем.
знаменитый бестолковый пример x/y:
имеем 2 файла cpp
первый файл
extern int x;
int y = x+1;

второй файл
extern int y;
int x = y+1;

понятно, что в зависимости от того какой файл выполнится первым будет другой результат. В эккеле утверждается , что для всех статических объектов (наверно имеется ввиду выделяющихся в статической области памяти) механизм компоновки и загрузки гарантирует гарантирует , что перед выполнением динамической инициализации, определяемой программистом , статические данные будут инициализированы нулями.
в связи с этим непонимание . Верно ли я понимаю , что к примеру если срабатывает файл №1 первым
x это грубо говоря никакое не объявление , а уже полноценное определение так как приобретает и адрес и значение ноль ???

Comment: Для исходного файла это объявление. В нем будет записано, что есть переменная `x` с некоторым адресом, каковой будет известен позже. Он и станет известен позже - при линковке...

Comment: Это объявление, которое только добавляет символ `i` в текущую область видимости. *"понятно, что в зависимости от того какой файл выполнится первым будет другой результат"* - нет, тут имеет место неопределенное поведение и результат непредсказуем

Comment: @user7860670 а что значит символ i ?

Comment: символ - это последовательность букв, который вы используете в данном случае для обращения у переменной

Comment: @user7860670 в чем выражается UB , что может выполнится первым первый файл, а может он выполнится вторым ?

Comment: Независимо от порядка выполнения при инициализации глобальной переменной будет обращение к еще не инициализированному объекту из другой единицы трансляции. Заметьте, что предварительное заполнение нулями не делает эти объекты инициализированными. Это заполнение работает только когда объект с тривиальным конструктором инициализируется этим самым конструктором.

Comment: @user7860670 так так и написано, что это только для выполнения динамической инициализации

Comment: А фаза динамической инициализации не разрешает обращаться к неинициализированным объектам. Собственно это никогда не разрешено.

Comment: @user7860670 ну наверно поэтому и заполлнение нулями.

Comment: Нет, заполнение нулями происходит ДО фазы динамической инициализации. В приведенном примере объекты `x` `y`, хотя и предварительно заполнены нулями, но все еще не инициализированы и обращаться к ним нельзя.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть скажем сработал первый файл первым(если несложно поправьте меня , а то представление корявое насчет "сработал файл" то есть линковщик подхватил файл первым ?) и уже в x и y забиты нулями и имеют адреса https://hkar.ru/13B7n

Comment: В любом случае x и y в начале динамической инициализации уже имею адрес и забиты нулями. Но обращаться к ним до инициализации нельзя.

Comment: @user7860670  не ответили на мои вопросы :))) а что значит обращаться нельзя ? мы наверно и не обратимся . обратиться можем только в main . нет ?

Comment: Переменная определенная в файле "подхваченным" первым будет равна 1, а во втором -- 2 (по крайней мере в `5.4.0-58-generic #64~18.04.1-Ubuntu`

Comment: @avp от компилятора наверно это зависит или от звезд в небе, это тут не суть.

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, безусловно. От компилятора, линкера, загрузчика, стартового кода (часть библиотеки компилятора), т.е. от *конкретной системы программирования* в целом (а вот "звезды на небе" (UB) это в головах)

Comment: Тут возможно два варианта: 1) сначала выполняется инициализация y: `int y = x+1;` - тут идет обращение к переменной `x`, которая в этот момент еще не инициализирована; 2) сначала выполняется инициализация x: `int x = y+1;` - тут идет обращение к переменной `y`, которая в этот момент еще не инициализирована. Как видно, в обоих вариантах получается тыква. А вот при каких конкретных условиях в исполняемом файле будет возникать вариант 1 или 2 - хз.

Comment: Подход, что если в команде линкеру сначала идет объектный файл с инициализацией x, а потом потом объектный файл с инициализацией y, то код инициализации будет выполняться именно в такой последовательности, наивен и не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Для исходного файла это объявление. В нем будет записано, что есть переменная x с некоторым адресом, каковой будет известен позже. Он и станет известен позже - при линковке...

Вот как это выглядит в VC++:

```
extern int y;
int x = y + 1;
```

Вот ассемблер: где-то вне объявляется `y`

```
EXTRN   ?y@@3HA:DWORD                   ; y
```

внутри объявляется и определяется `x` - у нее есть свое место в памяти и конкретный адрес:

```
_BSS    SEGMENT
?x@@3HA DD  01H DUP (?)             ; x
_BSS    ENDS
```

и добавляется код инициализации:

```
??__Ex@@YAXXZ PROC                  ; `dynamic initializer for 'x'', COMDAT
; File G:\Tmp\Test\x.cpp
; Line 2
    mov eax, DWORD PTR ?y@@3HA          ; y
    inc eax
    mov DWORD PTR ?x@@3HA, eax          ; x
    ret 0
??__Ex@@YAXXZ ENDP                  ; `dynamic initializer for 'x''
```

который ссылается на внешнюю переменную.

Точно так же работает и во втором файле - с внешней `x`.

Ну, а развязка адресов происходит уже на этапе линковки (компоновки), а не компиляции. Не говоря уж о получении значений переменными, которое тут получается уже только при выполнении...